# PhoneGap build. Why isn't my config.xml information showing with my build? No errors

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I uploaded a zipped folder with my config.xml file in the root. I don't get any build errors. After the build it doesn't show any plugins, any icons, any information in my config.xml file whatsoever. The only notification I get is "This app isn't using the latest version of PhoneGap. We recommend upgrading to 3.7.0." — in fact, it shows PhoneGap Build 3.3.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id        = "com.parker.products.2015"
versionCode="1"
version   = "0.0.1">
<name>Products</name>
<description>Easily view Parker Aerospace products and component information on iOS devices for reference or convenient use with customers and industry colleagues.</description>
<gap:platform name="ios" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024 " />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"  />
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
</widget>
```

I've been trying to figure this out for days. Any ideas?

Comment: After practically rebuilding the app from scratch, I found an old index.html file that had been copied into an image file. I never saw it and wouldn't have even thoughto check in that folder to update any code. Somehow, that file made my config.xml seem nonexistent.

Answer (score 0):

@Lisa, sometimes when the compiler fails, it drops references after that. Try removing all your plugins and add them back one at a time. It is tedious, but I found one bug like that. **NOTE:** It might be easier to start with a blank App, then to use the one you've put hours into.

FWIW: I do every plugin in a simple App, then add it to my main App. This allows me to test that plugin for bugs, then when I find them (bugs) I do less backtracking. It works sometimes.  --Jesse

Comment: thank you for your response. I don't know what it means to add one plugin back at a time. Aren't plugins added by just writing them in the config.xml? What is weird is that this is an app I built last year and it worked just fine. All I did was go in and update contact information for a person since someone left the company. I uploaded the build and all of a sudden it is like its cacheing old version. I even deleted the entire app, changed the name of the zipped file, added a new app to PhoneGap Build, and it still showed the old information from that previous app. I'm baffled.

Comment: @LisaG. Your response suggests you are not familair with using/building with Phonegap.  You did not say this App was in maintenance mode (ie. in the field, in production)  I suggest you transfer your question (with more information) to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap for Phongap CLI (Command Line Interface) or http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi for PhonegapBuild, the cloud base IDE. I'm on both forums and will see you there. Please have more complete information on this. If you have another question, I will monitor this forum.

Comment: Thank you, @JesseMonroy650, for taking the time to articulate a response. I realized, late last night that an index.html file was accidentally duplicated in a folder with several image files where it shouldn't be. I never even saw it. I guess this can easily happen when files are shared with a group of people, especially with the group includes people who are not designers or developers.

Comment: Okay. The important part is you resolved your issue. Best of luck.